# C# interface programming, how to ensure return value is serializable

Tags: c#

I wish I can do something like this for my interface

```
public T GetAStuff() where T is serializable
```

as a result, I want to guanrantee the implementors to return a serializable output

Can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by serializable. There are many ways to serialise objects in .NET. And they are all incompatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there is no common definition of "serializable" there. It depends hugely on the serializer, and many of the requirements are attribute-based, which cannot be expressed as a generic constraint.

- `BinaryFormatter` needs just `[Serializable]`, or possibly `ISerializable`
- `XmlSerializer` needs `public` and a public parameterless constructor (so `T : new()` would help), and optionally `IXmlSerializable` (but: it is very rare because it is horrible)
- `DataContractSerializer` can use the `XmlSerializer` setup, or use `[DataContract]`, but does not require a public parameterless constructor
- JSON.NET, protobuf-net, etc can work with a range of attributes or runtime configuration, and may-or-may-not use a constructor

Your best bet is to check the specific `T` details you need at runtime, or simpler: just make sure your unit/integration tests cover all the scenarios it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IFoo
{
    T GetAStuff<T>() where T : ISerializable; // or what ever you need to constrain T to
}
```

-or-

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : ISerializable
{
    T GetAStuff();
}
```

Since there are many different serialization options, you may not be able restrict the type.  If you only need to handle one serialization option, then it may be possible.

Comment: The problem is, most "serializable" types, **even those that are intended for `BinaryFormatter`**, do not use `ISerializable` - they just use `[Serializable]`, which cannot be specified in a constraint

Comment: exactly, Marc, could you sugguest the code for the xml serializer? Thanks

Comment: @TOMMYWANG I covered that in my answer; `XmlSerializer` will demand a public parameterless ctor, which you can enforce with `T : new()` - however, that isn't *everything* it needs; for example, it also needs to be `public`, which can't be enforced as a generic constraint. There are many types that `XmlSerializer` *fundamentally* cannot handle, too - and there's no way of saying that on a generic constraint either.